# Semantic UI Tab history on reload

Tags: semantic-ui

So I have a menu with 3 tabs. In each of these tabs there is a pagination for the related data. However when I go to page 2 in tab2, it reloads the page and by default the first tab is selected. I would need a way to keep the tab i was looking at.

Comment: Can you share or create a jsfiddle with your scenario? :)

Comment: here you can view it https://jsfiddle.net/jxLd33jg/2/

Comment: of course nothing happens I removed all the php framework logic. The thing i'd like is that when i click on page2 tab2 when the page reloads, tab2 must be active.

Comment: I'm not a semantic-ui expert but seems to me that there is no way to control this with semantic-ui itself. Maybe an option is to track the current tab for the user (in request, session...) and use it when page loads to set the active tab.

Comment: can't i just access tabs via id or something... i saw the history option was a thing but didn't understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the history option like so:

```
$('.ui.menu .item')
  .tab({
    history: true,
    historyType: 'hash'
  });
```

it requires [Asual's Address library](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address)